# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GraphQLModule

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Im trying to add a graphql server to nestjs based on documentation, but im getting this error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GraphQLModule (HttpAdapterHost, GqlModuleOptions, GraphQLFactory, GraphQLTypesLoader, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [4] is available in the GraphQLModule context. +19ms
```

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GraphQLModule (HttpAdapterHost, GqlModuleOptions, GraphQLFactory, GraphQLTypesLoader, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [4] is available in the GraphQLModule context.

Comment: Is this a new GraphQL module that you're adding in? It's coming from the @nestjs/graphql package right? Where are you importing the GraphQLModule? Without seeing more code it's practically impossible to tell where the error is. Are you sure you have all the necessary dependencies installed?

Comment: Yes, of course is weird i created new project a add this package and all work. I don't know why not work with my previous project.  I was investigating the code and the error seems to have to do so applicationConfig: ApplicationConfig is not passed to the module constructor

Comment: Have you updated all your dependencies? Can you share the code that's introducing the problem? It's pretty hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Sometimes deleting your node_modules directory and running npm install again fixes bugs like this.  Be sure that the GraphQL dependences are in your package.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After check all my dependencies i saw that the command installed me the last version of @nestjs/graphql and my @nestjs/core was incompatible i needed to update my nestjs. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your Versions does not compatible.

From the docs itself: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start

```
WARNING
@nestjs/graphql@^9 is compatible with Apollo v3 (check out Apollo Server 3 migration guide for more details), while @nestjs/graphql@^8 only supports Apollo v2 (e.g., apollo-server-express@2.x.x package). Both versions (v9 and v8) are fully compatible with Nest v8 (@nestjs/common@^8, @nestjs/core@^8, etc.).
```